# Python opencv error (-215:Assertion failed) 0 <= scaleIdx && scaleIdx < (int)scaleData->size() in CascadeClassifier.detectMultiScale

Tags: python, opencv, face-detection, assertion

I'm using the CascadeClassifier of the opencv-python package to perform face detection with the haarcascade_frontalface_default.xml with this code:

```
self.face_cascade = cv2.CascadeClassifier(haar_cascade_path)

...

gray_frame = cv2.cvtColor(frame,cv2.COLOR_BGR2GRAY)
faces = self.face_cascade.detectMultiScale(gray_frame, 1.3, 5)
```

It's working fine for most of the frames, but sometimes I'm getting this exception:

```
cv2.error: OpenCV(4.6.0) d:\a\opencv-python\opencv-python\opencv\modules\objdetect\src\cascadedetect.hpp:46: error: (-215:Assertion failed) 0 <= scaleIdx && scaleIdx < (int)scaleData->size() in function 'cv::FeatureEvaluator::getScaleData'
```

The error occurs during the `detectMultiScale` call. I already checked the gray_frame and it looks good (shape is 1366x1060 and it's not none or something like that). Do you have any idea on how the fix this?

Comment: [mre] please, including all required input data. save the frame (data) at the time of the exception, see if that reliably caused the issue.

Comment: @ChristophRackwitz I can't post the frame here, because it's extracted from a video of a private dataset. But I'm 100% sure, that the frame is fine.

Comment: a MRE (code at least) is important because it would have revealed the existence of multithreading. I had no reason to suspect thread-safety to be the cause.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I actually managed to solve this issue. What caused this error to happen was, that I'm preprocessing the dataset multithreaded and I only used a single instance for multiple workers concurrently. It seems like the CascadeClassifier (or at least the detect method) isn't thread-safe and feeding images with a different size concurrently caused the problem. Creating one instance for each thread/worker solved the issue.